# EJB3Unit testing no-tx-datasource

Tags: database, unit-testing, ejb-3.0

I am doing tests on an ejb3-project using ejb3unit http://ejb3unit.sourceforge.net/Session-Bean.html for testing. All my Services long for @PersistenceContext (UnitName=bla). I set up the ejb3unit.properties like this:

```
ejb3unit_jndi.1.isSessionBean=true
ejb3unit_jndi.1.jndiName=ejb/MyServiceBean
ejb3unit_jndi.1.className=com.company.project.MyServiceBean
```

everything works with the in-memory-database.

So now i want additionally test another servicebean with @PersistenceContext (UnitName=*noTxDatasource*) that goes for a  defined in my datasources.xml:

```
<datasources>
   <local-tx-datasource>
    ...
   </local-tx-datasource>
   <no-tx-datasource>
     <jndi-name>noTxDatasource</jndi-name>
     <connection-url>...</connection-url>
     <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
     <user-name>bla</user-name>
     <password>bla</password>
   </no-tx-datasource>
 </datasources>
```

How do I tell ejb3unit to make this work:

```
Object object = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/noTxDatasource");
if (object instanceof DataSource) {
  return ((DataSource) object).getConnection();
} else { 
  return null;
}
```

Currently it fails saying: javax.NamingException: Cannot find the name (noTxDataSource) in the JNDI tree Current bindings: (ejb/MyServiceBean=com.company.project.MyServiceBean)

How can I add this no-tx-datasource to the jndi bindings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but I had some simple thought:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
  OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();
  ds.setServerName("localhost");
  ds.setPortName(1521);
  ds.setDatabaseName("database"); // SID
  ds.setUser("user");
  ds.setPassword("pass");

  InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
  ic.add("noTxDatasource", ds);
}
```

This will additionally allow you to make the following lookup work:

```
Object object = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/noTxDatasource");
```

delivering a datasource (in this case oracle).